# How to fix missing data in an .sql file

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using sql for the first time. I've been given a huge .sql file, which is in fact a dump file. There are lost of entries in the file that have miising fields - ids, price, description etc.

How do I go about doing that. Is there a s/w I can use to easily locate where the entries are missing?

Comment: What do you want to do, do you need to select the records with missing values or excluding the missing values? If you need the records with the missing values then use the query **select * from table_name where ids is null or price is null or description is null**

Comment: just search for '' or NULL in the script..You will get to know all the occurrences.MOreover there are tools in internet just to compare two database and others..I hope not for this..

Comment: @Ajeesh : select count(*) from variants where product_id is null gives me 40 as the output. How do access/view these 40 records and update them

Comment: Just use **select * from variants where conditions** so that you can view the records and to update those records you have to use procedures. Have a look at using procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for

```
select * from Table where Field is null
```

repeat for your fields or combine:

```
select * from table 
 where ((Field1 is null) or (Field2 is null) or (Field3 is null))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had already commented this line

```
select * 
from table_name 
where ids is null or price is null or description is null
```

to select all empty records from database. Now without using procedures you can do a simple blind update which means you can't update all records with different values by this

```
update table_name 
set ids='value1', price='value2', description='value3' 
where ids is null or price is null or description is null
```

This can only be done if you don't care about the importance of the data.